# Incrementar versão automaticamente, e obter número de versão via código

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

No software em que estou trabalhando existem usuários, cujas dúvidas devem ser atendidas observando-se o número de versão do software.

Algo do tipo 10.0.1.1000 configurado nas propriedades do projeto.

Gostaria de saber como faço para incrementar o número de versão automaticamente num projeto do Visual Studio, para facilitar o build, e como obter esse número de versão via código, para que eu possa exibi-lo para o usuário.

Comment: aaah miguelito =*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Podes usar um asterisco para "pedir" ao Visual Studio para auto-incrementar a versao da assembly

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.*")
```

O numero de build (3o digito) corresponde ao numero de dias passados desde o inicio do ano 2000 e vai ser incrementado diariamente, e o numero da revision (4o digito) corresponde a' quantidade de segundos passados desde a meia noite do dia actual.

Podes encontrar mais informacao acerca destas regras [aqui](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblyversionattribute.aspx).
Se quiseres ter mais controlo sobre a versao da assembly, recomendo o uso de um "build server" ou servidor de integracao continua (ex: [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/)).

Para obter programaticamente a versao da assembly, tens que usar reflection:

```
string version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

Answer (score 5):

Só para complementar, também é possível editar o atributo `AssemblyVersion` pela caixa de dialogo de configuração do projeto, nas propriedades do projeto... o atalho geralmente é `ALT + ENTER`, e depois clica em `Assembly Information` na guia principal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

```
private string ObterVersaoApp()
{
    return string.Format("[versão {0}]", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version);
}
```