# Incrementando o AssemblyVersion

Tags: c#, versionamento, visual-studio-2012, .net-assembly

Estou criando uma solução de atualização para uma aplicação que tenho e precisei da versão do Assembly

Ao colocar um * no assembly.

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.*")]
```

ele começou a incrementar automaticamente, porem a forma que está incrementando é adicionado 5 digitos na última casa.
Ex.

```
1.0.0.29058
```

Gostaria de saber se é possível configurar o AssemblyVersion para que ele incremente automaticamente e com apenas um dígito na última casa para facilitar a comparação entre versões.

Estou obtendo o AssemblyVersion na aplicação da seguinte forma:

```
string versionAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

e a comparação que estou utilizando na aplicação é:

```
 if (Convert.ToDouble(version) >= Convert.ToDouble(versionAssembly))
 {
     //code here
 }
```

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2867/incrementar-versao-automaticamente-e-obter-numero-de-versao-via-codigo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nesse caso, ao colocar `*` em seu arquivo `AssemblyInfo.cs` você está obtendo a quantidade de segundos passados desde a meia noite (seguindo o [Tempo Universal Coordenado](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tempo_Universal_Coordenado)) dividida por dois.

Para fazer o incremento com apenas um dígito, sugiro que dê uma olhada no [Build Version Increment](https://autobuildversion.codeplex.com/documentation). As versões oficiais abrangem até o VS 2010, mas você pode obter uma modificação para o 2012 [aqui](https://docs.google.com/folderview?id=0B1dGyLef9er3aWZoRWNFRUk4Wlk). Acessando as configurações, você poderá mudar o estilo de versionamento do último identificador (casa) para **Increment**, acrescentando +1 à cada compilação.

**Alternativamente**, você poderia seguir o padrão de uso do `*`

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("x.x.*")]
```

para atribuir o número de dias passados desde o início de janeiro do ano 2000 ao penúltimo indicador de versão, e ao último a contagem de segundos como apontado acima. Depois, bastaria fazer uma comparação "*DateTime*" para determinar a versão mais recente conforme seja necessário.

---

**Nota**: Sugiro que analise cautelosamente o modo como a identificação de versionamento será feita pois, adaptando-a às características de desenvolvimento do projeto, o gerenciamento dos resultados das equipes ou etapas de desenvolvimento se torna mais funcional. Adaptando a [documentação da MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.version%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), o versionamento pode ser brevemente representado da seguinte maneira: `VersãoPrincipal.VersãoMenor.Compilação.Revisão`

- Versão Principal: pode indicar uma reescrita do produto em que não se garante a compatibilidade com versões precedentes, indicando a efetuação de amplas modificações.
- Versão Menor: pode representar um ponto de lançamento do produto em que modificações de menor escala foram incluídas, podendo ou não manter a compatibilidade.
- Compilação: representa a recompilação do código, sendo que seu número pode ser modificado em casos de mudança de processador, plataforma ou compilador.
- Revisão: consiste em pequenos reparos que tendem a garantir a total compatibilidade com versões anteriores.

Contudo, em certos casos pode ser viável inverter os dois últimos identificadores (compilação e revisão). Deste modo, a revisão poderia representar um conserto (sem que haja inserção de novas funcionalidades) ao laçamento de uma Versão Menor, e a compilação simplesmente identificar o último *build* em questão.