# Qual a forma correta de mudar a versão do software em C# a cada compilação?

Tags: c#, versionamento

Atualmente eu altero direto no arquivo assembly.

Comment: Relacionada(?):[Incrementando o AssemblyVersion](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11473/incrementando-o-assemblyversion?rq=1)

Comment: Se não for duplicata, a pergunta é ampola ou não está clara.

Comment: Então. . Eu gostaria de saber se essa eh a forma correta de se fazer. Ou o padrão de se fazer isso.